# convert html tables to monospace font plain text tables?

Tags: c#, .net, html

Trying to find a proper way to transform HTMl talbles into plain text tables. Anyone know if there is a good tool out? either payware or freeware. Preferably in .net (C#).
I've looked in to doing it via HTML agility pack, maybe there are better ways? Using a html parser would still leave a lot of the complexity e.g. to calculate column widths and table widths with different colspan and so on...

Thanks!

Here is a example:
http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/tables.html#h-11.5

I'm actually working with financial tables, that have more varying colspan, but the example points out what I want to achieve. It must also be possible to limit the width of the table.

Comment: What format do you want your "plain text tables" to be?

Comment: This could probably be done using Regular Expressions, but I would need a sample of how you expect the output to look like before I could be sure. Would you update the question with a sample, please?

Comment: added example for table.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [source code to Links](http://sourceforge.net/projects/links/).  It is a text-based web browser, so it knows how to render tables as text.  It's written in C, not C#, but it should be enough for you to figure out a mapping algorithm.